# Writing an implementation of Show

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write my own implementation of show for my Tree type. But the following code:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance Show (Tree a) where
    show (Branch a b) = show $ "<" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show b ++ ">"
    show (Leaf a) = show a
```

is yielding:

```
main.hs:11:21: error:
    • No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
    • In the expression: show a
      In an equation for ‘show’: show (Leaf a) = show a
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Tree a)’
   |
11 |     show (Leaf a) = show a
   |                     ^^^^^^
```

I don't really understand what the compiler is telling me.

What would be the correct implementation and why?

Comment: Well Haskell says that it can not per se call `show a`, you should add `Show a` as type constraint.

Comment: You don't need to use `show` in the result of `"<" ++ ... ++ ">"`; it's already a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly state that there exists a `Show` instance for the type variable `a`:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Tree a) where
  show (Branch a b) = show $ "<" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show b ++ ">"
  show (Leaf a) = show a
```

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation, you write:

```
instance Show (Tree a) where
    show (Branch a b) = show $ "<" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show b ++ ">"
    show (Leaf a) = show a
```

That thus means that you call `show` on an `a` object. But Haskell has no guarantees that it can call `show` on `a`. So you need to add a type constraint `Show a`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
    show (Branch a b) = show $ "<" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show b ++ ">"
    show (Leaf a) = show a
```